# Postgres: Unsafe use of new value of enum type

Tags: postgresql, constraint, enum

I want to alter a constraint after I have added a new value to an enum I use. So I originally have an enum called activity_state where I want to add a new value. But I also need to change the constraint I put on the field completed_at.

```
  `DO $$ BEGIN
    CREATE TYPE activity_state AS ENUM ('TODO', 'SCHEDULED', 'DONE');
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN duplicate_object THEN null;
  END $$;

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${activitiesTable} (
    ...
    state activity_state NOT NULL,
    completed_at timestamptz CHECK (
         (completed_at IS NULL AND state != 'DONE')
      OR (completed_at IS NOT NULL AND state = 'DONE')
    ),
  );

  -- Alter state enum
  ALTER TYPE activity_state ADD VALUE IF NOT EXISTS 'DONE_BY_PASSED';

  -- Alter constrain on
  ALTER TABLE ${activitiesTable} DROP CONSTRAINT maintenance_activities_check;
  ALTER TABLE ${activitiesTable} ADD CONSTRAINT maintenance_activities_check CHECK (
         (completed_at IS NULL AND (state != 'DONE' OR state != 'DONE_BY_PASSED'))
      OR (completed_at IS NOT NULL AND (state = 'DONE' OR state = 'DONE_BY_PASSED'))
    );
```

The enum seems to be added correctly, but once I use it my new check constraint I get the error:
`error: unsafe use of new value "DONE_BY_PASSED" of enum type activity_state`

Not sure how I can alter my constrain once the enum is changed? I am using postgres 12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forgotten to show us the hint you got:

```
ERROR:  unsafe use of new value "DONE_BY_PASSED" of enum type activity_state
HINT:  New enum values must be committed before they can be used.
```

You also forgot to mention that you ran the `ALTER TYPE` and the `ALTER TABLE` statements in the same transaction.

Like the hint says, you have to commit the `ALTER TYPE` before you can use the new enum value.

Comment: This is the reason StackExchange lost all of it's users. There is no reason to have the under-tone of "you dummy, the answer was already in the Hint!". FYI, it might not be obvious to a new user. Show some empathy @Laurnenz Albe

Comment: @JasonRoell If I hadn't had empathy, I would have ignored the question or I would have written a comment.